# SSAS incremental cube processing shows wrong distinct count

Tags: count, ssas, distinct

I have created XMLA to process cube in incremental way. It is using type "ProcessUpdate" for dimensions and "ProcessAdd" for measurement partitions. I am facing one issue on distinct count. Let me take one example:

```
Order Id    CustId  Amount

1       C1  100.00

2       C2  200.00

3       C3  300.00

4       C4  400.00

5       C5  500.00
```

If we browse cube, SSAS shows sum of orders as 1500.00, and distinct customer count for all orders as 5. Now adding new fact record for cancelling one order, 
e.g.:

```
Order Id    CustId  Amount

3       C3  -300.00
```

After incremental processing, it shows sum of orders as 1200.00 which is correct one. But the distinct customer count for all orders keeps same and shows 5 which is incorrect.
I can understand that the rows are getting append on incremental process which works for sum operation, but fails computing distinct count. I want to know if there is any way that can remove order #3 from all aggregate operation while processing in incremental way.

Answer (score 1):

Distinct customer count remaining at five is correct, as it doesn't know that a minus 300 means the customer shouldn't show. If you processed the cube fully it would show as 5 distinct customers.

This isn't to do with incremental processing, this is to do with how SSAS handles distinct count - It's just "Count distinct customer Ids in fact table", and C3 is there twice with a sale of 300 and a sale of -300.

You need to reconsider how to handle this, ideally at the stage where you load your data warehouse. You could handle it in MDX by not including anyone who has sales of zero or less, but then the whole distinct count calculation will be done in MDX and will be much, much slower.

Comment: Actually I am removing entry from main data source, so on processing cube fully, it will show proper distinct count as 4. I am maintaining delta source just for incremental processing. I am looking for the way to remove existing entry from SSAS fact on incremental process just before it process aggregations. Is there any different way to maintain delta source to remove existing fact entry? I agree as you said, handling in MDX will take long.

Comment: @user2652816 - Sorry, are you saying you're deleting the C3 row? Your example above looks like you're adding a new row for C3 with an amount of -300? There is no way to remove fact rows during an incremental load - You'd need to fully process the affected partition.

Comment: Because of the huge database, fully process takes 7 to 8 hours, which is increasing by 1 hour every month. I have to look for incremental processing anyways. If it is not possible to ignore existing fact entries, then this is serious limitation of incremental processing in context of distinct count.

Comment: @user2652816 look at using partitions, and fully processing only the partitions you need to. Also consider if you can change the design at all, as your current method doesn't sound like it will work in a year or so - How will you handle schema deployments where you need to recreate the cube? http://sql-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/dynamic-cube-partitioning-in-ssas-2008.html

Comment: You must be correct about this limitation, but I haven't found it is documented anywhere. Well, Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: I agree on dynamic partitions, even it is needed. Currently there are around 60 dimenstions/attributes, 25 measures, KPIs, etc. Some of my customers not allowing to use Enterprise Edition. I don't think I can go for dynamic partitions.

Comment: @user2652816, yes, on Standard edition you will only get 3 partitions per measure group I think. With incremental processing it is "additive" only, so your idea to add a minus data row works for sales amounts (300 + minus 300 = zero) but it can't work with distinct counts, as you can't remove the existing row with an incremental process. Might be worth looking at factless fact tables, you might be able to use them to incrementally load while saying "This row means don't include in the distinct count", but it will be difficult. http://dwhlaureate.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/factless-fact-table.html